# Aborting HttpGet is not working on Android 2.2 and below

Tags: android, apache, http, sockets

I am performing a long-living HTTP-GET request on android, using the Apache http classes. As I want to interrupt this request at any time, I call abort() on this HttpGet from another thread (from the main thread). The blocking call of HttpClient.execute() returns, as an IOException is thrown immediately. All works as I expect it on Android 2.3.

When I run the same code on Android 2.2 (tested on HTC Desire and Emulator), no Exception is thrown. The loading-thread is still blocking. I have got no chance to interrupt it.

My first guess was, that android 2.2 is using an older version of the Apache HTTP Client. So I included the latest version as a library (with a different namespace) and checked my imports. --> same result.

Any ideas, why it's not working on android 2.2 (and probaply earlier)?

Comment: To reliably abort HTTP requests: Supply a ClientConnectionManager to your HttpClient and call #shutdown() on the ClientConnectionManager to abort (all) requests. That usually jars the request loose.

Comment: Hi Jens, and thanks for your answer! I tried to call myHttpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown() instead of myRequest.abort(). But my loading thread is still blocking, till the timeout was reached.

Comment: Ah snap, forgot - you need SO-timeout set to something (non-zero) also - then the shutdown should work. Basically, the socket read wasn't paying the least bit attention to interrupts or anything similar in 2.2. I think this is the issue they fixed http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7933

Comment: I found a different thread about this topic. They suggest to create a new SocketFactory and invoke #shutdownInput() on the blocking socket. My first attempts succeeded, so I think I'll give it a try. Found this at: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7496.